# How to calculate this integration?

Tags: integration

Assume that $\beta＞\alpha＞0$

How to calculate$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\alpha x^{2}}-e^{-\beta x^{2}}}{x^{2}}dx$$？

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First rewrite the integrand as an integral.
$$\mathcal{I}\stackrel{def}{=}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-ax^2} - e^{-bx^2}}{x^2}dx
= \int_0^\infty \int_a^b e^{-ux^2} du dx$$
Since $e^{-ux^2}$ is non-negative, we can switch order of integration
and get
$$\mathcal{I} = \int_a^b \int_0^\infty e^{-ux^2} dx du
= \int_a^b \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{u}} du = \sqrt{\pi b} - \sqrt{\pi a}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose fix $\alpha$ consider $\beta$ as a parameter, i.e. look at the function
\begin{align}
f(\beta) = \int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-\alpha x^2}-e^{-\beta x^2}}{x^2}\ dx.
\end{align}
Observe
\begin{align}
f'(\beta) = \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^2e^{-\beta x^2}}{x^2}\ dx = \int^\infty_0 e^{-\beta x^2}\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\beta}}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
f(\beta) = C+\sqrt{\pi\beta}
\end{align}
Set $\beta= \alpha$, we have that
\begin{align}
f(\alpha)=C+\sqrt{\pi\alpha}=0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ C=-\sqrt{\pi\alpha}.
\end{align}
Thus, it follows
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-\alpha x^2}-e^{-\beta x^2}}{x^2}\ dx = \sqrt{\pi\beta}-\sqrt{\pi\alpha}
\end{align}